# How can I express the multinomial theorem by sum and production for $(a+b+c)$?

Tags: combinatorics

How can I express the multinomial theorem for $(a+b+c)$?

$$\begin{align*}\left(x_1+x_2+x_3\right)^2=\sum _{k_1+k_2+k_3=2} \left(\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ k_1,k_2,k_3 \end{array}\right)\prod _{1\leq t\leq n} x_t^{k_t}\end{align*}$$

How about the case: $(a+b+c)^2$?

Comment: Those are the same case. Just with different letters.

Comment: @anon yes, they are.

Comment: @User19912312, if you know so, then why are you asking this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(x_1+x_2+\ldots +x_m)^n=\sum _{k_1+k_2+\ldots +k_m=n} \left(\begin{array}{c} n,  k_1,k_2,\ldots, k_m\end{array}\right)\prod _{1\leq t\leq m} x_t^{k_t}$.

For $m=3$ you get

$(a+b+c)^n=\sum _{k_1+k_2+k_3=n} \left(\begin{array}{c} n,  k_1,k_2, k_3\end{array}\right)a^{k_1}b^{k_2}c^{k_3}$.

Comment: How to use  ${a,b,c}$in left?

Comment: I added my answer.